# Accessing column of a data frame doesn't require the full name of that column

Tags: r, dataframe

Here's my issue :

```
df <- data.frame(xabc = c(1,2,3), yabc = c(4,5,6))
```

Accessing a column of this `data.frame` is usually performed using `df$xabc`. While realizing of a typo, it seemed that accessing that exact same column using `df$x` works as well...

My question is :

- How is this process called ?
- What kind of errors/mistakes could arise if a typo is to be made ?
- If any, is there anything to do to raise an error if the column name after the `$` doesn't exist ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `[[` or `[` if you want to match the whole string `x[["xabc"]]` or `x[, "xabc"]`, the `[[` should be general as it works on tibble and data.table as well to extract as vector.  Partial matching can lead to buggy situations if there are multiple colums that have the same prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `` ?`[` ``:

> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

Below you can see the first and third are equivalent. The `$` operator keeps `exact = FALSE` whereas with `[` you can specify explicitly to control this behavior although the default is `TRUE`.

I don't know if there's a specific name for this behavior, but as @akrun comments, this could produce unpredictable and undesirable results, so it's better to enforce exact matching or if fuzzy matching is required, do so in a more explicitly controlled way.

```r
d <- data.frame(xabc = c(1,2,3), yabc = c(4,5,6))

d$x
#> [1] 1 2 3
d[["x"]]
#> NULL
d[["x", exact = F]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
d[["x", exact = T]]
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>